# Non Square Matrix Multiplication Help C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, multiplication

first off sorry for the slightly messy code as I was fiddling with different things to try to get it to work. As of now, my code can multiply Square Matrices just fine; however, it has difficulties computing Non Square Matrices. My best guess after debugging is how i re-size my vectors, and that there is an out of bounds error which causes the program to crash. Any help would be appreciated, my code should be able to Multiply any Vectors sizes withing Matrix Multiplication Rules.

I also would like to note this is a HW assignment so I am limited to how I can build my code, basically ONLY using vectors, cannot write your own class etc....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void multiply_matrices(vector <vector<int> > matrix1,vector <vector<int> > matrix2, int cols, int rows2); 
void setMatrix(vector <vector<int> > &matrix, int rows, int cols);

int main()
{
    int rows, cols, rows2, cols2;    
    vector< vector<int> > matrix, matrix2;        
    cout<<"Please enter the number of Rows and Columns for your first Matrix."<<endl;
    cout<<"Rows: ";
    cin>>rows;
    cout<<"Columns: ";
    cin>>cols;

    matrix.resize(cols, vector<int>(rows,0));  //Saw this online so not sure how it works but it works, if i take out one i cant do row<column and vice versa
    matrix.resize(rows, vector<int>(cols,0));

    cout<<"Size has been declared, please enter data for your matrix"<<endl;

    setMatrix(matrix,rows,cols);

    cout<<"Second Matrix Automatically Set by Matrix Multiplication Rule"<<endl; //Just automatically sets second matrix as per Matrix Multiplication Rule
    rows2=cols;
    cols2=rows;
    cout<<"Second Matrix Size is: " << rows2 << " by " << cols2 << endl;
    matrix2.resize(cols2, vector<int>(rows2,0));
    matrix2.resize(rows2, vector<int>(cols2,0));

    setMatrix(matrix2,rows2,cols2);        

    cout<<"Multiplied Matrix is:"<<endl;
    multiply_matrices(matrix,matrix2,cols,rows2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void setMatrix(vector <vector<int> > &matrix, int rows,int cols){
     int num;
     for(int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Value for Row " << (i+1) << " Column " << (j+1) << ": ";
            cin>>num;
            matrix[i][j]=num;            
        }        
        cout <<  endl;
    }

 /*for(int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }       
        cout <<  endl;
    }          
  */   
     }
void multiply_matrices(vector <vector<int> > matrix1,vector <vector<int> > matrix2, int cols, int rows2){
    vector< vector<int> > tempMatrix;
    int newrows=rows2;
    int newcols=cols;
    int sum;
    tempMatrix.resize(newcols, vector<int>(newrows,0));   //Resizing new matrix to proper size, so if it was (2x3)(3x2), new matrix is (3x3)

    for (int i = 0; i < newrows; i++)                    //This Works Fine for Square Matrixes but not for others, i have no clue how to fix it?
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < newcols; j++){
            //sum=0;    
            for (int u = 0; u < newcols; u++)
            {
                //sum+=matrix1[i][u] * matrix2[u][j];
                //tempMatrix[i][j]=sum;
                tempMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][u] * matrix2[u][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < newrows; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < newcols; j++)
        {
            cout << tempMatrix[i][j] << " ";
        }        
        cout <<  endl;
    }          
}
```

Comment: Well, one way to make your code safer is to limit your loops using vector::size(), not variables that can easily have the wrong maximum value.  Better yet, use iterators that go from begin() to end().

Comment: `I also would like to note this is a HW assignment so I am limited to how I can build my code, basically ONLY using vectors, cannot write your own class etc....`  Wow.  Finally a HW assignment that actually allows you to use C++.  Usually we get the opposite on SO, where the student can't use `vector`.

Comment: Yeah I am very new to 2D Vectors, so i don't know the proper format implementation to check the size in a 2D array.

Comment: Why do you need to pass `rows` and `cols` to `setMatrix`?  A vector knows its own size without having to pass these values.  Unless you need to size the matrix first before you start your input loop?

Comment: it's for the for loops, again i am unfamiliar how to use 2D array size implementation and proper comparison for it, so it's easier for me to use the rows and cols to go through the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your first matrix like this:

```
matrix.resize(rows, vector<int>(cols,0));
```

and your second like this:

```
matrix2.resize(rows2, vector<int>(cols2,0));
```

where `rows2 = cols`. Note that there is no "multiplication rule" that implies `cols2 == rows`.

The problem is in your `multiply_matrices` function where the loops should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) // or matrix1.size()
for (int j = 0; j < cols2; j++) // or tempMatrix[i].size()
for (int u = 0; u < cols; u++) // or rows2 or matrix1[i].size()
```

but as already stated in the comments, it would be better to use `vector::size()` instead of passing the sizes as additional parameters.

Also, if you multiply (2x3)(3x2), the result is (2x2):

```
tempMatrix.resize(rows, vector<int>(cols2,0));
```

Comment: yes thank you, it should be 2x2 had it backwards thanks. Lemme me fiddle a bit with everyone's suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Dude THANK YOU! Testing it and SO FAR it works perfectly! Basically a logic issue. But I would be very grateful if you could show me the loops using the vector::size() so I could properly implement 2D array loops in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the `resize()` function.  What may be wrong is that you ignore the maximum size and rely solely on variables that are passed to your functions.

For example, your `setMatrix` function is passed `rows` and `cols`, but this is not necessary.

The function should be rewritten using only the matrix to provide the sizes to the loops:

```
void setMatrix(vector<vector<int> > &matrix)
{
     int num;
     for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            cout << "Enter Value for Row " << (i+1) << " Column " << (j+1) << ": ";
            cin>>num;
            matrix[i][j] = num;            
        }        
        cout <<  endl;
    }
}
```

You have the same issue with `multiply_matrix`.  What you should be doing is ensure that you're loops use the return value of `vector::size()`, which you do not do.  The problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newrows; i++)    
{
    for (int j = 0; j < newcols; j++)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < newcols; u++)
        {
            tempMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][u] * matrix2[u][j];
```

You sized the `tempMatrix` to `newrows` rows and `newcols` columns.  But how do you know that `matrix1` and `matrix2` have at least `newrows` rows and `newcols` columns? You don't know, but you just assume they do.

So you either need to ensure that the size of matrix1 and matrix2 can accommodate the number of rows/columns, or you throttle those loops to use the minimum rows/columns.

Overall, the issue is that nowhere do you use `vector::size()` in your code that I see.  So start to use `size()` to your advantage -- don't create superfluous (and possibly erroneously set) variables that supposedly denote the sizes of the rows and columns.

Comment: would this be correct for the multiplication for (int i = 0; i < tempMatrix.size()/*newrows*/; i++)                    //This Works Fine for Square Matrixes but not for others, i have no clue how to fix it?
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempMatrix[i].size()/*newcols*/; j++){
            //sum=0;    
            for (int u = 0; u < tempMatrix[j].size() /*newcols*/; u++)
            {
                //sum+=matrix1[i][u] * matrix2[u][j];
                //tempMatrix[i][j]=sum;
                tempMatrix[i][j] += matrix1[i][u] * matrix2[u][j];
            }
        }
    }

Comment: oi sorry just copy paste starting from the first for, also pretty bad with the website features -_-